# ¿Cómo modificar datos en una tabla dinámica?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="caja6">
```

## DETALLE MATERIALES, REPUESTO E INSUMOS

```
<br>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo">
   <div class='btn btn-success' id="btnNuevaDetalleMaterialEinsumo">Nueva</div>
 </label>
 <table class='table table-bordered table-hover' id="tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo">
  <tr>
    <th>Detalles De Insumos</th>
    <th>Unidad</th>
    <th>Cantidad</th>
    <th>Precio Unitario</th>
    <th>Valor Total ($)</th>
    <th>OPCION</th>
  </tr>
  <?php for($i=0; $i<sizeof($detalle_insumo); ++$i) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="detalle_insumo[]" id="detalle_insumo[]" value="<?= $detalle_insumo[$i][0] ?>" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="unidad_insumo[]" id="unidad_insumo[]" value="<?= $detalle_unidad[$i][0] ?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="cantidad_insumo[]" id="cantidad_insumo[]" value="<?= $detalle_cantidad[$i][0] ?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="precio_unitario_insumo[]" id="precio_unitario_insumo[]" value="<?= $detalle_precio_unitario_dia[$i][0] ?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor_total_insumo[]" id="valor_total_insumo[]" value="<?= $detalle_valor_total[$i][0] ?>" readonly ></td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <div class='btn btn-info'>Eliminar</div>

    </td>

  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

```
functionfuncNuevaDetalleMaterialEinsumo()   {
$("#tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo")
.append
(
  $('<tr>')
  .append
  (
    $('<td>')
    .append
    (
      $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'detalle_insumo[]')
      )
    )
  .append
  (
    $('<td>')
    .append
    (
      $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'unidad_insumo[]')
      )
    )
  .append
  (
    $('<td>')
    .append
    (
      $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'cantidad_insumo[]')
      )
    )
  .append
  (
   $('<td>')
   .append
   (
    $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'precio_unitario_insumo[]')
    )
   )
  .append
  (
   $('<td>')
   .append
   (
    $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'valor_total_insumo[]').prop('readonly', true)
    )
   )
  .append
  (
    $('<td>').addClass('text-center')
    .append
    (
      $('<div>').addClass('btn btn-info').text('Eliminar')
      )        
    ) 
  );   sumaValores();     }




   sumaTotales = function(){


   var totales = 0;


   $('tr','#tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo').each(function(){


   var campo_total = $(this).find('input[type="text"]:eq(4)');

  var numero = parseInt(campo_total.val()); totales += isNaN(numero) ? 0 : 
  numero; 

 });

$('#valor_unitario').val(totales);

$('#suma_1').val(totales);

};
var sumaValores = function(){

var fila = $("#tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo").find('tr:last');

var campo1 = fila.find('input[type="text"]:eq(2)'); 

var campo2 = fila.find('input[type="text"]:eq(3)');

var destino = fila.find('input[type="text"]:eq(4)');

campo1.on('change', function(){
  destino.val(parseInt(campo1.val())*parseInt(campo2.val()));
    sumaTotales();
    sumaTotalGeneral();
  });

campo2.on('change', function(){
  destino.val(parseInt(campo1.val())*parseInt(campo2.val()));
    sumaTotales();
    sumaTotalGeneral();
  });   };
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @Dariel Ramos Díaz de Villegas, esta es mi duda, saludos

Comment: @DarielRAmosDiazdeVillega

Comment: @Dariel Ramos, te agradeceria mucho si me puedes ayudar en esa parte, de verdad, estaria eternamente agradecido o alguien que se maneje un poco mas, dado que soy novato en eso.

Comment: Lo que quieres es que calcule en las filas que son creadas desde la BD igual que cuando la agregas dinámicamente???

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas exactamente, porque al momento de leer los datos de la bbdd, puedo modificar un valor. no se si logras entenderme. Saludos

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas, lo otro es que yo guardo varias columna en la bbdd y despues las vuelvo a leer porque puedo agregar o eliminar columna, pero la que ya estan creada, esa no puedo modificar o sea no fui capaz de hacerlo y las que agrego si se calcula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno si lo que buscas es que realice los mismos cálculos que cuando ingresas una fila dinámicamente solo tienes que llamar a las funciones que hacen tus cálculos. Tu javascript, el mismo que pusistes en tu pregunta debe quedar tal como te lo dejo aquí.

```
function funcNuevaDetalleMaterialEinsumo()   {
$("#tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo")
.append
(
  $('<tr>')
  .append
  (
    $('<td>')
    .append
    (
      $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'detalle_insumo[]')
      )
    )
  .append
  (
    $('<td>')
    .append
    (
      $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'unidad_insumo[]')
      )
    )
  .append
  (
    $('<td>')
    .append
    (
      $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'cantidad_insumo[]')
      )
    )
  .append
  (
   $('<td>')
   .append
   (
    $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'precio_unitario_insumo[]')
    )
   )
  .append
  (
   $('<td>')
   .append
   (
    $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'valor_total_insumo[]').prop('readonly', true)
    )
   )
  .append
  (
    $('<td>').addClass('text-center')
    .append
    (
      $('<div>').addClass('btn btn-info').text('Eliminar')
      )        
    ) 
  ); 
  //Obtengo la última fila de la tabla que por ende debe ser la ingresado dinámicamente
  var fila = $("#tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo").find('tr:last');
  //Le paso esa misma fila a esta función para asignarle el calculo de los valores en los campos textos
  sumaValores(fila);
}

sumaTotales = function(){
   var totales = 0;
   $('tr','#tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo').each(function(){
    var campo_total = $(this).find('input[type="text"]:eq(4)');
    var numero = parseInt(campo_total.val()); totales += isNaN(numero) ? 0 : numero; 
    });

    $('#valor_unitario').val(totales);
    $('#suma_1').val(totales);
};

//Aquí establecí un parámetro a la función para buscar en cualquier fila que le pase
var sumaValores = function(fila){
    var campo1 = fila.find('input[type="text"]:eq(2)');
    var campo2 = fila.find('input[type="text"]:eq(3)');
    var destino = fila.find('input[type="text"]:eq(4)');

    campo1.on('change', function(){
      destino.val(parseInt(campo1.val())*parseInt(campo2.val()));
        sumaTotales();
        sumaTotalGeneral();
      });

    campo2.on('change', function(){
      destino.val(parseInt(campo1.val())*parseInt(campo2.val()));
        sumaTotales();
        sumaTotalGeneral();
    });   
};

//Esto es nuevo, lo que hago es decirle que asigne el calculo de los valores a los campos de cada fila en la tabla
$('tr', '#tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo').each(function(){
   sumaValores($(this));
});
```

Te documenté las cosas nuevas y porque lo hice. Espero que resuelvas. Saludos

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67378/discussion-on-answer-by-dariel-ramos-diaz-de-villegas-como-modificar-datos-en-u).

Comment: OKOK no hay de que ;)

Comment: Qué sucede??? Monsiens

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas, me puedes ayudar en una parte del codigo porfa.

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas te escribo por lo de los colores en la tabla no me funciona :(    var class = colorsStyle[mes]; esta bien despues de var vaya class? saludos